# Woocommerce Subscriptions and synced force sell doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to create a situation in which a guarantee (no VAT) is automatically added to the cart when you order a variable subscription product. This should be done only one with the first transaction, not with the next payment in the subscription, therefore a grouped product construction.
I try to do this with the plugins mentioned above, but it simply doesn't appear in the shopping cart.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

For the grouped product, see also: https://www.rentyourmac.com/product/the-master-macbook-test-subscription/

Comment: Maybe you should [better use the fee api](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees) to add an insurance on an ordrered subscription

Comment: Thx for your answer. The problem is only that these fees will also be applied to renewal subscriptions, but should only be applied with the 1st subscription

Comment: The fee is only applied to the subscription **first order** when customer place the order.

Comment: I have tested the WC Product Fees plugin and it seems to work regarding VAT and language. Only it's being added to the first order, but also to the recurring subscriptions, how can I change this in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to use a plugin… See all [those related questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees) … Then choose the most convenient code trying to change it for your needs… Now you can include that code in your question, giving all use details. Remember that StackOverFlow is code oriented and we are expecting to find some code in your question that shows your effort. Without it your question will remain unanswered or will be closed as too broad.